# i am trying to import sbt for a spark project in intellij but it throws an error

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

actually I am knew to spark and scala, I am trying to import sbt(1.7.2) on spark 3.1.2 but it shows an error that is shown in screenshot. This is the screenshoot

[image]

Comment: Hey! I'm not sure if this would solve the error, but [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core) tells that spark 3.1.2 is NOT compatible with scala 2.13. You should try ```scalaVersion := 2.12.10```. Also, mark spark-core also as *provided*

Comment: @o_O Could you please why the spark-core is marked 'provided'?

Comment: I assume that you'll be submitting your Scala 'uber/fat' jar to a spark cluster running somewhere. That cluster would already have the spark-core package handy. So we don't need to include it in our Scala jar. If however, that's not the case, you should keep it